# How can I stop prints of xcodebuild to consol in macOS

Tags: xcode, bash, terminal

I want make xcodebuild in Terminal without those extra long long prints, for that goal I am using quiet code, but it seems not working! How can I stop prints?

```
xcodebuild archive \
-scheme Test \
-configuration Release \
//some other codes ...
-SKIP_INSTALL=NO \
-BUILD_LIBRARIES_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES \
-quiet=YES
```

Comment: Why not pipe the output to dev null?

Comment: I like to know about it, if it help me to stop those extra long prints